# std::tie fails with "cannot bind non-const lvalue reference" when passed value from a function call

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, lvalue

I expected this code to work, but it does not compile:

```
#include <tuple>

struct S
{
    int x = 0;
    int y() const { return 1; }
};

bool f(const S& a, const S& b)
{
    return std::tie(a.x, a.y()) < std::tie(b.x, b.y());
}
```

GCC 9 says:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'

```
return std::tie(a.x, a.y()) < std::tie(b.x, b.y());
                     ~~~^~
```

What's wrong with the code, how can it be fixed, and why?  I'm trying to write a concise comparison function, and usually `std::tie` supports that (indeed this is the textbook use case for `std::tie`).

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/cWbQC0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::tie` takes lvalue references as arguments, so `int` returned by `S::y` can't bind. You could use the perfect forwarding version, `std::forward_as_tuple`, instead:

```
#include <tuple>

struct S
{
    int x = 0;
    int y() const { return 1; }
};

bool f(const S& a, const S& b)
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(a.x, a.y()) < std::forward_as_tuple(b.x, b.y());
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/T_4XfN)

Comment: Good solution, but then why does `tie` exist--is there some use case where `tie` is preferable to `forward_as_tuple`?

Comment: `tie` is the usual case: `std::tie(a.x, a.y)` or especially `std::tie(a, b) = set.insert(x)`. `forward_as_tuple` is for a more general, more C++11-ish situation where you might have rvalue references and stuff. [`boost::tie`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#tiers) (which became `std::tie`) pre-dates C++11 rvalue references.

Answer (score 8):

`std::tie` always expects lvalues for arguments, since its intended purpose is to be used in assignment. To handle other value categories, one may use [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple):

```
bool f(const S& a, const S& b)
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(a.x, a.y()) < std::forward_as_tuple(b.x, b.y());
}
```

The two tuples now contain rvalue references that are bound to the results of the calls to `S::y`. Goes without saying that one best be careful with object lifetimes when using it.

Comment: As I said to @jrok: Good solution, but then why does tie exist--is there some use case where tie is preferable to forward_as_tuple?  It seems you can use forward_as_tuple instead of tie even for assignment.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - Different purposes warrant different utilities. `tie` is for unpacking tuples into existing variables. Forwarding is for working with general callables. I also think the former is far more frequently done than the later, which is why it gets such a short name. The use we (yes me too) make of those utilities to get comparison for free is a bit hackish.

Comment: That's quite unfortunate, as comparison operators are the second most common use case for `std::tie`.  Given they came into existence around the same time, it's weird that `tie` isn't implemented as `forward_as_tuple` (keeping only the nice short name).